# How to put a PHP variable inside a html file that is being created using fwrite()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to create many html files all using the same template. In this case:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <h1> This is //here goes the variable// 's profile</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to use different variables defined at the login (in this case "uname"). To do this I was using fwrite(). (usertest is the folder where all the files will be stored):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $uname = $_POST["uname"];
    $filecount = count(glob("usertest/*.html"));
    $filename = "user" .($filecount+1).".html";
    $myfile = fopen("usertest/$filename", "w") or die("unable to create file");
    $html = "<html><body><h1> This is" .$uname."'s profile</h1></body></html>";
    fwrite($myfile, $html);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

From this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mango.js"></script>
</head

<body>
    <form>
        <input id="userinput" type="text" name="uname" />
       <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" />

    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

And this Jquery (mango.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
     var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
     var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
     data = {'action': clickBtnValue};
     $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
         alert("success!");
     });
});
});
```

The file names are created perfectly and everything. However when I open the created html files they just read:

```
This is 's profile
```

They completely ignore the variable!
The question is, how do I include this PHP variable in the html? Or is it not possible?
Help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? maby echo $uname before written in the file, it could be an empty string or undefined, and the notices disabled

Comment: You are right, $uname isn't defined. Shakti Phartiyal's code below will define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not sending the uname to server in order to save it.
The js code should actually be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
     var unameValue = $('#userinput').val();
     var actionValue = $(this).val();
     var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
     data = {
        uname: unameValue,
        action: actionValue
     };
     $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
         alert("success!");
     });
});
});
```

notice that we are now send the uname as `uname: unameValue` value which you can capture in php as $_POST['uname'];

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `<form>` by `<form method="POST">` ?

By default `<form>` method is *GET*, so you will get nothing in `$_POST['uname']`

Otherwise, declare `$uname = $_GET['uname'];`

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$_POST["uname"]` is not empty in your php file, otherwise, the rest of the php seems ok.